# Nginx Redirect https://non-www to http://www not working

Tags: ssl, redirect, nginx

I've spend a bit of time searching for an answer to this but can't seem to lock it down and any help would be appreciated.

I've setup SSL on an Nginx server but can't seem to get the non-www https domain to redirect to the www https domain.

I am trying to fix this:

> https://example.com -> https://www.example.com

Below is my current config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {

    access_log /var/log/nginx/site.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/site.error.log;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    root /var/www/site;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    client_max_body_size 10m;

    # unless the request is for a valid file, send to bootstrap
    if (!-e $request_filename)
    {
        rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
    }

    # catch all
    error_page 404 /index.php;

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www/site$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to apache .htaccess files
    location ~ /\.ht
    {
        deny all;
    }


  location = /xmlrpc.php {
      deny all;
  }

    location ~* \.html$ {
        expires -1;
    }

  location ~ \.(htc|less|js|js2|js3|js4)$ {
      expires 31536000s;
      add_header Pragma "public";
      add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public";
      try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html /index.php?$args;
  }

  location ~ \.(css|html|htm|rtf|rtx|svg|svgz|txt|xsd|xsl|xml)$ {
      expires 3600s;
      add_header Pragma "public";
      add_header Cache-Control "max-age=3600, public";
      try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html /index.php?$args;
  }

  location ~ \.(asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|eot|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|json|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|mpp|otf|_otf|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tif|tiff|ttf|ttc|_ttf|wav|wma|wri|woff|woff2|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip)$ {
      expires 31536000s;
      add_header Pragma "public";
      add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public";
      try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html /index.php?$args;
  }

    location ~* \.(eot|ttf|woff)$ {
         add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;

    if ($scheme != "https") {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
```

> None of the below answers have resolved my issue's. I am currently hosting the site on AWS could it be the way I have setup my bucket to redirect to the domain?

Comment: Add listen 443 into second server block. I guess it's not finding https version because of it.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42228191/nginx-redirect-non-www-to-www-https/42230968#42230968) for guidance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nginx: Redirect non-www to www https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42228191/nginx-redirect-non-www-to-www-https)

Comment: None of the above have worked unfortunately, I even replaced it with Tarun's method. Same problem