# All endpoints other than root redirect to HTTPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, nginx, https, certbot

My address is `mousie.space`. The config below correctly enables: `https://mousie.space`, `https://www.mousie.space` and `http://www.mousie.space` and redirects `http://www.mousie.space` to `https://www.mousie.space` however it does not redirect `http://mousie.space` to `https://mousie.space`.

This is for a Rails application with Unicorn running on port 8080. I added the current HTTPS support by using certbot then tweaking it until at least most of the domains worked.
`/etc/letsencrypt/live/mousie.space-0002/` is a certificate for `*.mousie.space` and `mousie.space`.

The below config is hacked together from various examples and I don't really know what I'm doing here.

```
worker_processes 1;
user root root;

pid /var/run/nginx.pid;
error_log /var/log/nginx.error.log;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
  accept_mutex off;
  use epoll;
}

http {
  include mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  access_log /var/log/nginx.access.log combined;
  sendfile on;

  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay off;
  gzip on;
  gzip_http_version 1.0;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_min_length 500;
  gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";
  gzip_types text/plain text/html text/xml text/css
             text/comma-separated-values
             text/javascript application/x-javascript
             application/atom+xml;

  upstream app_server {
    server unix:/root/mousie/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
  }

  server {

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name *.mousie.space;
    keepalive_timeout 5;
    root /root/mousie/public;
    try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @app;

    location @app {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;

      proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
      root /root/mousie/public;
    }


    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mousie.space-0002/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mousie.space-0002/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}


  server {
    if ($host = mousie.space) {
        return 301 http://$host$request_uri;
    }


    server_name *.mousie.space;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mousie.space-0002/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mousie.space-0002/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; 


}


  server {
    if ($host ~ ^[^.]+\.mousie\.space$) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80 default deferred;
    server_name *.mousie.space;
    return 404;


}}
```

Comment: Take a look at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42228191/nginx-redirect-non-www-to-www-https/42230968#42230968).

Comment: @RichardSmith I don't quite understand how that would fit into my config (I don't want to break my routes again tbh).

Answer (score 0):

Of course it doesn't, in fact it does the opposite by the look of it:

```
if ($host = mousie.space) {
    return 301 http://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an ideal solution since in practice it redirects twice but it does work for all domains:

```
worker_processes 1;
user root root; # for systems with a "nogroup"
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;
error_log /var/log/nginx.error.log;

events {
  worker_connections 1024; # increase if you have lots of clients
  accept_mutex off; # "on" if nginx worker_processes > 1
  use epoll; # enable for Linux 2.6+

}

http {
  include mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  access_log /var/log/nginx.access.log combined;
  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on; # off may be better for *some* Comet/long-poll stuff
  tcp_nodelay off; # on may be better for some Comet/long-poll stuff

  gzip on;
  gzip_http_version 1.0;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_min_length 500;
  gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";
  gzip_types text/plain text/html text/xml text/css
             text/comma-separated-values
             text/javascript application/x-javascript
             application/atom+xml;

  upstream app_server {
    server unix:/root/mousie/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
  }

  server {
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name *.mousie.space;
    keepalive_timeout 5;
    root /root/mousie/public;
    try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @app;
    location @app {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
      root /root/mousie/public;
    }
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mousie.space-0002/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mousie.space-0002/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

  server {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    listen 80 default deferred;
    server_name *.mousie.space;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mousie.space-0002/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mousie.space-0002/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```