# Nginx www -> non www redirect

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, certbot

Followed the Certbot instructions when setting up the certs to redirect www traffic to non www but my site is still displaying both www and non www versions.

sites-available/app

```
server {

    server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/myusername/app/app.sock;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /home/myusername/app/app/static;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {

    if ($host = www.mysite.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = mysite.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

This is the original config created by Certbot, apart from the addition of the `static` alias

Tried a few different things but not been able to find a solution & ran `sudo systemctl reload nginx` after making changes.

Server is Ubuntu 18.04

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your config redirects `http` to `https`. It doesn't contain any code to redirect from `www` to non-`www` or vice versa. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42228191/nginx-redirect-non-www-to-www-https/42230968#42230968) for a possible solution.

Comment: Hi @RichardSmith, thanks for the feedback. I would have thought the second server block should handle the `www` to non `www` using the 2 `if` statements?

Comment: The second `server` block is only responsible for `http` to `https` redirection. The two `if` statements only change the scheme, the first one process `www` and keeps the `www`, and the second one processes non-`www` and keeps the non-`www`.