# Nginx: Do you need to redirect https://www to https://

Tags: nginx

I have just converted my website from `http://` to `https://`. I have set up the redirects and server as follows:

```
# Redirect all http:// to https://
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

# Server
server {
    listen 443 ssl; 
    server_name         example.com;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/metacraftuk.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/metacraftuk.com/privkey.pem;

    location / { 
        # do stuff    
    }
}
```

However, this means that if you visit `https://www.example.com`, there is no redirect in place.

Is it necessary to set up a redirect for this? If so, does that mean that I will need to get a unique certificate for `https://www.example.com` just so that I can redirect it?

The website was never located at `https://www.example.com`, so I'm wondering if it's actually necessary to take care of this redirect.

Comment: If you want to redirect www to non-www, you will need to add that domain to your generated certificate. Use [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42230968/4862445) to handle both `http` to `https` and www to non-www (but the other way around).

Comment: It depends on what user experience you would like to provide. If you don't care about users who access `https://www`, then do nothing. If you care, then @RichardSmith is right. Ideally, many sites use a wildcard certificate to cover all subdomains.

Comment: Thank you both. This command did the trick: `sudo certbot --nginx certonly --cert-name example.com -d example.com,www.example.com`. By adding the www. version of the domain to the certificate allowed me to set up a redirect in _nginx.conf_.