# ngix redirect to non www in ubuntu server

Tags: nginx, server, digital-ocean

I saw many solutions nothing is working for me. I am trying to redirect the user from www to non www url. Here is the server code I am using

```
 server {
    if ($host = https://www.example.com.com) {
        return 301 https://example.com.com$request_uri; // IT DOESN'T WORK
    } # managed by Certbot



    if ($host = www.example.com.com) {
         return 301 https://example.com.com$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = example.com.com) {
        return 301 https://example.com.com$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com.com www.example.com.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Comment: Is it normal that you have .com.com everywhere?

Comment: This server block only handles redirects from `http`. If you are trying to redirect from `https://www.example.com` to `https://example.com` you are looking in the wrong place. You could abandon the "managed by Cerbot" partial solution and use [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42230968/4862445).