# Redirecting a HTTPS domain to new HTTPS domain

Tags: url, nginx, redirect, server, url-rewriting

**Things to know:**

I'm using Vultr.com (similar to DigitalOcean) as my VPS and running 1 server with Nginx and Ubuntu 18.10 x64.

I have 2 domains I'm working with:

- `https://(www).oldsite.org`
- `https://(www).newsite.org`
- (www) = with and without the www prefix
- Both domains have SSL certs

**My Problem:**

Currently `https://(www)oldsite.org` is mirroring my `https://newsite.org`

If I remove `https://` and only go to `(www)oldsite.org` it redirects to `https://newsite.org` with no issues.

It's only when I add the `https://` that the mirroring happens.

**My Question:**

How can I fix my sites-available script to redirect `oldsite` to `newsite`?

I need the following to redirect like so:

- `https://www.oldsite.org` redirect to `https://newsite.org`
- `https://oldsite.org` redirect to `https://newsite.org`

**My Script:**

```
server {
root /var/www/newsite/public;
 server_name newsite.org www.newsite.org oldsite.org www.oldsite.org;

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/newsite.org-0001/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/newsite.org-0001/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {

    if ($host = www.newsite.org) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = newsite.org) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = oldsite.org) {
        rewrite ^ https://newsite.org$request_uri? permanent;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = www.oldsite.org) {
        rewrite ^ https://newsite.org$request_uri? permanent;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name newsite.org www.newsite.org oldsite.org www.oldsite.org;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

**Rather than doing this:**

```
    if ($host = oldsite.org) {
        rewrite ^ https://newsite.org$request_uri? permanent;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = www.oldsite.org) {
        rewrite ^ https://newsite.org$request_uri? permanent;
    } # managed by Certbot
```

Is there a `Wildcard` method I can use similar to this:

```
//NOTE THE * before oldsite.org

    if ($host = *oldsite.org) {
        rewrite ^ https://newsite.org$request_uri? permanent;
    } # managed by Certbot
```

That would be ideal if I could have any prefix someone might enter redirect to `https://newsite.org`

Would like to cover all bases and have each variation of these `oldsite` Url's redirect.

- `https://oldsite.org`
- `https://www.oldsite.org`
- `www.oldsite.org`
- `oldsite.org`

Thank you!

Comment: All `https` requests are handled by the first `server` block. You should split this into two separate blocks, one to handle the website and one to handle everything else. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42228191/nginx-redirect-non-www-to-www-https/42230968#42230968)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I recommend you to use separate configs for different sites. It's easier to manage.

I guess such variant of script could fix your issue:

```
server {
     listen 80;
     listen [::]:80;
     server_name oldsite.org www.oldsite.org;
     return 301 https://newsite.org$request_uri;
}

server {
     listen 443 ssl;
     listen [::]:443 ssl;
     server_name oldsite.org www.oldsite.org;
     return 301 https://newsite.org$request_uri;

     ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/newsite.org-0001/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
     ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/newsite.org-0001/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
     include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
     ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Comment: Creating a new server block and following your instructions worked great. Thanks!