# nginx handling redirects and rewrites of http and non-www urls

Tags: nginx

I've seen many ways of dealing with redirecting http://example.com or example.com (with or without www.) or https://example.com to https://www.example.com.

The way I use is in this nginx configuration:

```
error_log /dev/stdout info;

upstream django_server {
    server app:8001 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/certificate.chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload";

    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload";

    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 default_server ssl;
    server_name www.example.com;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    charset utf-8;
    keepalive_timeout 70;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload";

    gzip on;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";
    gzip_min_length 256;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css text/javascript application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss;
    gzip_comp_level 9;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/certificate.chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    location /static/ {
        root /usr/share/nginx/sasite/;
        expires 30d;
        autoindex off;

        location /static/download/ {
            location ~* \.(pdf|docx|zip|rar)$ {
                add_header Content-Disposition 'attachment; filename="$request_filename"';
            }
        }
    }
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_redirect off;
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://django_server;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

But I have also seen versions where multiple `server_name` values are set like so:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload";

    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 default_server ssl;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    charset utf-8;
    keepalive_timeout 70;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload";

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/certificate.chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

}
```

I've seen other ways to do it as well, that did not seem as effective.  What is the actual ideal approach to handling this scenario?  My current configuration works, but I'd like to learn the best practices.

Comment: I prefer [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42228191/nginx-redirect-non-www-to-www-https/42230968#42230968) but I would as I wrote it. The optimum approach is dependent on whether the IP address handles many different domains or only variations of a single domain.

Comment: @RichardSmith I do like that approach, but I have a question.  What does setting default_server achieve in the block where you do not set a server_name?  And when would the default_server block ever respond to a request on port 443?  Since the port is defined in both sections.

Comment: The block marked as a default server will respond to requests to any host name that does not match a specific `server_name`. So all host names that point to your IP address except the one specified in the other `server` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes down to preference.  Do you want your users to always see (or always not see) the "www." portion?  If so, use the redirect method.  If you don't care whether they see it or not, use multiple server_name/server_alias entries.