# Nginx - SSL - Redirect IP to domain issue

Tags: ssl, nginx, redirect

I've a django app running on ubuntu-18.04 & nginx at digitalocean.

I've set a pointed a domain to the app and enabled the self signed SSL using Certbot ( by following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-18-04])).

I have `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True` in `settings.py`

I'm trying to redirect all requests to the IP address to the domain name.

I've added

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name x.x.x.x;

    return 301 $scheme://mydomain.com$request_uri;
}
```

When access the app as `https://x.x.x.x`, it's not getting redirected. Instead it shows a Privacy error and by accepting it I can access the app with IP in url.

(I have not done the SSL steps for IP)

Should I need to redo all the steps to enable SSL for the IP address too for getting a redirect irrespective of http or https? - (I'm not sure whether this will work or not)

Thanks for any help.

**Edit:**

Thanks @Richard Smith for comments. I've got it working.

Comment: The `server` block in your question only handles redirection for `http` requests. You need to add redirection for `https`. For example, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42228191/nginx-redirect-non-www-to-www-https/42230968#42230968). But you will always get privacy errors with `https` from the browser for any domain name that does not have a valid certificate.

Comment: I've `cert.pem    chain.pem      fullchain.pem  privkey.pem` under '/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com'. What should I give for `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificate_key` - the filename/fullpath or something else?

Comment: Use: `ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem; ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem;`