# redirect non-www to www with SSL/HTTPS

Tags: nginx, redirect

I'm using nginx I got ssl certifice (using certbot) for "www".name.com. However, if i write name.com i got this message **not getting safe warning.**

I want like this ; http://name.com and https://name.com redirect to > https://www.name.com

How can i do ?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name name.com www.name.com

    location / {
    return 302 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {

    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.name.com;  #
    ...
```

Comment: If you want to redirect from `https://example.com` to `https://www.example.com` without the "not safe" warning, you will need to extend your certbot certificate to include both domain names. To perform the actual redirections, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42228191/nginx-redirect-non-www-to-www-https/42230968#42230968)

Comment: http:// name. com work http:// www. name.com work https:// www. name.com However https:// name.com doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do a 301 redirect (Permanent redirect) to https and www. Not an expert on this but I would try with the following:

```js
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name name.com www.name.com;
    return 301 https://www.name.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name name.com;
    ssl_certificate /mydirectory/name.com/name.in.cer;
    ssl_certificate_key /mydirectory/name.com/name.in.key;
    return 301 https://www.name.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: it is work but have a problem if i write "https:// name . com" in any dnslookup website or pagespeed website ( doesn't work)

Comment: You may need to specify the path to ssl_certificate and ssl_certificate_key in listen on 443, see my updated answer.