# www.example.com is insecure but example.com is secure

Tags: django, nginx, server

Currently when i enter the following urls , all are redirected to https://example.com and i want this to happen only.

```
http://example.com
example.com
https://example.com
```

But when i enter the following urls then they are not getting redirected to https://example.com instead **Not secure** connection gets open

```
www.example.com 
http://www.example.com
https://www.example.com
```

This is myapp.conf in /etc/nginx/sites-available/

```
server {

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    server_name example.com; # managed by Certbot

    location /static/ {  alias   /home/datasleek/tracker/staticfiles/; }
    location /media/ {  alias   /home/datasleek/tracker/media/; }

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://unix:/home/datasleek/trackervenv/tracker/daphne.sock;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
                  }


    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/datasleekapp.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/datasleekapp.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
 }

server 
 {
  if ($host = example.com) 
   {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
   } # managed by Certbot
  listen 80 ;
  listen [::]:80  ;
  server_name example.com;
  return 404; # managed by Certbot
 }

server 
{
  if ($host = www.example.com) 
  {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  } # managed by Certbot

  listen 80 ;
  listen [::]:80  ;
  server_name www.example.com;
  return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Following are allowed hosts in project settings of my django app.

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [ 'example.com','www.example.com' ]
```

Comment: you're only listening to port 443 for example.com, not for www.example.com.

Comment: Do you have a certificate for `www.example.com`?

Comment: @dirkgroten I added www.example.com in server name still it's showing Not secure.

Comment: @RichardSmith do i have to get separate certificate for example.com and www.example.com  each? Please pardon me i do not have much knowledge about this.

Comment: Not necessarily. You can generate a single certificate covering both domain names.

Comment: @RichardSmith What you have said that's correct. When i first install certbot  i didnot mention www.example.com at that time. I put this later in myapp.conf file. Now what i did. I again run the commands. Old certificate has been replaced with the new one covering example.com and www.example.com  both. May you please write this as an answer so that i can accept. Thanks and regards.

Comment: Now that you have the correct certificate, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42228191/nginx-redirect-non-www-to-www-https/42230968#42230968) to get the redirection working properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198535/discussion-between-ashok-kumar-and-richard-smith).