# Nginx redirect not working when redirect all cases to https and non-www

Tags: nginx, redirect, certbot

I found an answer here but still can make it work, I want just the same thing as him:

```
https://example.com
https://www.example.com
http://example.com
http://www.example.com
example.com
www.example.com

to all redirect to `https://example.com`
```

here is my config file

```
server {
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;

    # listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
    }

    server_name example.com;
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

all the redirects are correct except "https://www.example.com", it does not redirect at all.

Where did I do wrong? Please help!

Comment: Check you configuration using `nginx -t`. You have multiple `server` blocks with the same `server_name`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42228191/nginx-redirect-non-www-to-www-https/42230968#42230968) for one possible solution.

Comment: I followed the link you provided, but still no hope, I posted the changed code here https://pastebin.com/qSkbK6bU but it dont even redirect `http://example.com`

Answer (score 0):

Your cerbot generated configuration looks strange. As mentioned in a comment. Check `sudo nginx -t` to see if there are any warnings.

To redirect the client request that's sent to https://www.example.com you need a server blog matching www.example.com liste 443 ssl. Please make sure you have the certs including www.example.com as a CN!

In this server blog you can create a redirect with `return 301 https://example.com$reuest_uri`

Certbot should! generate the right configuration for ssl if your configuration for port 80 (non-ssl) is correct.

```
server {
server_name example.com;
listen 80;

...
}

server {
server_name www.example.com;
listen 80;

return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;

...
}
```

This should generate the right ssl configuration using the nginx certbot plugin.