# How to redirect www to no-www URL - Nginx

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, url, server

I am using DigitalOcean to host my Django app and I am trying to forward all the www.example.com URLs to example.com. I am also using Let's Encrypt to enable HTTPS, so if anyone can help me please let me know.

**/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default**

```
server {
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    # Let's Encrypt parameters
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
        proxy_redirect     off;

        proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    }
}
```

Comment: Same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42228191/nginx-redirect-non-www-to-www-https/42230968#42230968) but reversed.