# nginx www vhost, is not redirecting to non-www https:// site

Tags: nginx, virtualhost, nginx-config

I have a site that works with

```
domain.com --> redirects to https://example.com
https://example.com --> works fine
https://www.example.com --> redirects to https://example.com --> works fine
www.example.com --> 404 error --> should redirect to https://example.com
```

This is my virtual host with de name example.com

```
    server {
   server_name myip domain.com www.example.com;
   root /var/www/cra-myapp/myapp/LandingPage/my-default-starter/public;
   index index.html index.htm;
   location / {
   try_files $uri /index.html =404;
   }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


   server_name myip example.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}

server {
   listen 443;
   server_name www.example.com;
   return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Whats the issue there? I have generated the ssl config with   which adds some configuration blocks

```
sudo certbot --nginx -d example.com -d www.example.com
```

Comment: Remove `www.example.com` from the `listen 443` block, add to `listen 80` and add a redirect

Comment: @0stone0 I have, removed the last block and added.
```server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.example.com
  return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;

}
``` But it doesnt seem to work, is that what you meant?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42228191/nginx-redirect-non-www-to-www-https/42230968#42230968).