# How to remove underscore (-) before the root domain

Tags: nginx

I see Google currently indexing pages with an additional underscore.

Example, I've this page [www.domain.com/page1](http://www.domain.com/page1)
but now I see a duplicate content on https://_www.domain.com/page1.

I'm using nginx. Can anyone suggest a safe 301 for this.

Comment: Create a default server to handle any invalid domain name. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42228191/nginx-redirect-non-www-to-www-https/42230968#42230968).

Comment: yes. it worked.