# Fixing NGINX configuration for http+non-www to https+www redirect

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, nginx, certbot

I'm struggling to get my Nginx configuration right on my `Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS`.

My goal: to have a good and secure Nginx configuration that only has the minimum required lines to have all `http and non-www` traffic 301 redirected to `https+www` version.

I do have a working configuration, but it's not elegant. I am seeking a good configuration that I can be proud of.

```
server {

        root /var/www/mydomain/public;

        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        charset utf-8;

        server_name www.mydomain.com;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
                deny all;
        }

        listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    }
    
    
    server {
        if ($host = mydomain.com) {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot


            listen 80;

            server_name mydomain.com;
        return 404; # managed by Certbot


    }server {
        if ($host = www.mydomain.com) {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot


            listen 80 default_server;
            listen [::]:80 default_server;

            server_name www.mydomain.com;
        return 404; # managed by Certbot


    }
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42228191/nginx-redirect-non-www-to-www-https/42230968#42230968).

Comment: @RichardSmith - Do I need to obtain SSL certificate for both 'www' and 'non-www'? Looking at the suggested answer, it looks like only the 'www' (aka desired) version has the SSL certificate. It's confusing because both server blocks have pointers to SSL certificate. I'm not sure if these pointers should be moved outside of the server block as suggested in the answer. I'm using Letsencrypt for certificates; and it doesn't show a wildcard certificate option. Bit confusing. Is there any resource I could refer to that explains this for a novice?