# Nginx - non-www to www redirect not working for subfolders

Tags: nginx, redirect, webserver

I'm trying to redirect everything under `example.com/`.* to [www.example.com/..](http://www.example.com/..). by tweaking the sites-enabled settings in `Nginx`.

I've managed to make it work for the homepage only, but when I try to access a subfolder like `example.com/es/`, this is not redirecting to `www.example.com/es/`.

These are my current settings:

```
server {
        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

        location /core/static {

        alias /home/andrea/agency/core/static/;

    }


        location / {
                include proxy_params;
                 proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
        }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://www.$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

I though the `$request_uri` part would take care of everything that's under the `non-www` domain, but it doesn't seem to work.

Do you have any hint why this is not behaving as expected? Many thanks!

Comment: Your testing is probably being confused by the browser cache and the presence of HSTS headers. But you should be using a solution that covers all cases, such as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42228191/nginx-redirect-non-www-to-www-https/42230968#42230968)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone having a similar issue, this is how I eventually solved it

```
server {
  
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
    }

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location /core/static {

        alias /home/andrea/agency/core/static/;

    }

    location / {

        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }


    listen 443 ssl; 
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; 
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; 
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; 

}

server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }


    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
    } 

    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; 

}
```