# https www to non www (NGINX)

Tags: node.js, nginx, mern

Im new to all this, but how do i redirect my from www to a non-www. I have tried multiple ways to fix it in  NGINX but no mater how i change it, there is still a www and an non-www site. The payment gateway is redirected to a non-www website after a transaction.

```
server {
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    location / {
    proxy_pass http://123.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
     }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/dineshudayan.tech/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/dineshudayan.tech/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name  www.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

   


}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name admin.example.com www.admin.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://123.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
     }
}
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42228191/nginx-redirect-non-www-to-www-https/42230968#42230968).

Comment: You want to redirect https www.example.com to https example.com?

Comment: @jaygooby, yeh, thats what im hoping to do

Comment: @RichardSmith, i did look into that too.... but that didn't work either for me as well. I'mnot really sure if i entered the code wrong tho.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nginx no-www to www and www to no-www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947030/nginx-no-www-to-www-and-www-to-no-www)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@richard-smith is right; here's a fully worked example with some comments:

```
# Your default server - assuming DNS is set up correctly
# will serve http & https requests for any *.example.com
# hosts and redirect to them to https://example.com
server {
    listen  80 default_server;
    listen  443 ssl default_server;

    server_name www.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/dineshudayan.tech/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/dineshudayan.tech/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    # redirect all requests to https://example.com
    return  301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

# http server for example.com
# - will redirect requests to https://example.com
server {
    listen  80;

    server_name example.com;

    # redirect all requests to https://example.com
    return  301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

# Your example.com https server
server {
    listen  443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/dineshudayan.tech/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/dineshudayan.tech/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}
```