# Only redirect from non-www to www not working, www and non-www both are working on nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect

i have a nginx server which is serving my django application. I have SSL and redirection from non-www to www all setup configured but the redirection is not working. After doing **`curl -IL http:example.com`** 

 its showing **`301 moved permanently`** and also **`200 found`**.

 But I need only the **`301 moved permanently`** which will redirect my web page from **`https:example.com`** to **`https://www.example.com`**

My configuration on nginx.conf

```
server {
    # Server 1 example.com
    server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
    }
}
```

So how could I fix the problem? Thanks in advance.

 The redirection successfully happens when **I remove the s** from **`https://example.com`** then it redirects to **`https://www.example.com`**

 So when I type **`http://example.com`** then it redirects to **`https://www.example.com`**

 But I need to enable redirection like **`https://example.com`** to **`https://www.example.com`**

 but now both URL are working no like https://example.com and https://www.example.com

 
Need a quick fix on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42228191/nginx-redirect-non-www-to-www-https/42230968#42230968).