# How to redirect https://www.example.com to https://example.com with Nginx?

Tags: nginx, ssl, redirect, certbot

I have PHP webapplication running on a VPS, served by Nginx. It's already live, under https://thebedechkacase.com.

I have my SSL certificate setup automatically via Certbot. I want to have all my pages only to be accessible under the www-less domain and only via secure protocol (for SEO-reasons).

I already have some redirects in place in my Nginx config:

`www.thebedechkacase.com` redirects to `https://thebedechkacase.com` with a 301, same for `http://thebedechkacase.com` and `http://www.thebedechkacase.com`.

But if someone tries to access the site via `https://www.thebedechkacase.com`, they are met with **Warning: Potential Security Risk Ahead** error message from the browser (which is understandable since I don't have a wildcard certificate, so the `www` sub-domain is not included).

What I would like to do is to redirect also `https://www.thebedechkacase.com/*` to `https://thebedechkacase.com/*`.

Currently my Nginx config looks like this:

```
server {  
  # Path to the application
  root /var/www/thebedechkacase.com/public; 

  server_name thebedechkacase.com; 
  
  location / {
    # try to serve file directly, fallback to index.php
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
  }

  location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;

        # optionally set the value of the environment variables used in the application
        # fastcgi_param APP_ENV prod;
        # fastcgi_param APP_SECRET <app-secret-id>;
        # fastcgi_param DATABASE_URL "mysql://db_user:db_pass@host:3306/db_name";

        # When you are using symlinks to link the document root to the
        # current version of your application, you should pass the real
        # application path instead of the path to the symlink to PHP
        # FPM.
        # Otherwise, PHP's OPcache may not properly detect changes to
        # your PHP files (see https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/126
        # for more information).
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        # Prevents URIs that include the front controller. This will 404:
        # http://domain.tld/index.php/some-path
        # Remove the internal directive to allow URIs like this
        internal;
    }


  # SSL settings automatically added by Certbot
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2 ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
  listen 443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/thebedechkacase.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/thebedechkacase.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
  # Commented out because HTTP2 needs newer chipers
  # include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
  # Define the allowed chipers
  ssl_ciphers EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

# return 404 for all other php files not matching the front controller
    # this prevents access to other php files you don't want to be accessible.
    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }

  # Don't serve .htaccess files
  location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
  }

  # Disable PHP execution for upload directory
  location /public/uploads/ {
    location ~ \.php$ {return 403;}
  }

  # Turn on Gzip
  gzip on;
  # Make sure images js css are always gzipped
  gzip_types application/javascript image/* text/css;
  gunzip on;

  # Expire rules for static content

  # cache.appcache, your document html and data
  location ~* \.(?:manifest|appcache|html?|xml|json)$ {
   expires -1; # Don't cache
  }

  # Media: images, icons, video, audio
  location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|webp|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm)$ {
    expires 1M; # One month
    access_log off;
    add_header Cache-Control "private";
  }

  # CSS and Javascript
  location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
    expires 1y; # One year
    access_log off;
    add_header Cache-Control "private";
  }
}
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;

  # Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
  if ($host = thebedechkacase.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  } # managed by Certbot


  server_name thebedechkacase.com;
  return 404; # managed by Certbot

  # redirect all requests to HTTPS
  if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }
}
# Redirect all www to non-www
server {
   server_name www.thebedechkacase.com;
   return 301 $scheme://thebedechkacase.com$request_uri;
}
server {
   server_name https://www.thebedechkacase.com;
   return 301 $scheme://thebedechkacase.com$request_uri;
}
```

As you can see I have two `server` block at the end that take care of redirecting `http` to `https` and one that redirects `www` to `non-www`.
But why are these not working for the mentioned `https://www.thebedechkacase.com` scenario?

Comment: https uses port 443. You only have one `server` block which listens on port 443.

Comment: @RichardSmith - Yes, and I have the lines 

`listen [::]:443 ssl http2 ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot`
`listen 443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot`
In the first server-block, if I understand it correctly this makes HTTPS work as a whole. I've tried changing `80` to `443` in the last `server` block, but then Nginx fails and the website is not served.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42228191/nginx-redirect-non-www-to-www-https/42230968#42230968).